# Drag and drop a div to print it

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and need some solid help. I want to write a code that can 
help me drag and drop a div to print it. In below code, if I drag div with id "A1" and drop it to div with id "target", it should print the text under the div A1. Similarly, dragging and dropping A2 should print the text in A2.

```
<div id="droptarget">
   <img src="print.jpg />
</div>
<div id="A1">
   This is text A1
</div>
<div id="A2">
   This is text A2
</div>
```

Any help will be really appreciated.